# How to open a webpage in firfox using Python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, firefox, sudo, python-webbrowser

I am working on a project where I need to open a `url` in firefox in Ubuntu using python. For this I have below code:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
```

This works fine in windows and it open `google.com` in default browser available in OS. But in case of Ubuntu, I am getting below error for firefox:

```
[6858:6858:0929/111955.830869:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[6868:6868:0929/111955.853440:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.
```

I thought of installing chrome and then using chrome in webbrowser code. But still its same. I even tried modifying the `google-chrome` file but it kept throwing same error. For some reason, I have to run the code as sudo and thus need this. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: Why don’t you switch user and then launch the browser?

Comment: @xrisk How to switch user from inside the code.?

Comment: Maybe place the code that launches the browser inside a separate script and then use `subprocess.call` along with su.

Comment: It seems that you are running the python script as root. Do you really need it? Try running the script as a regular user (as always recommended).

Comment: @xrisk Can you please explain how to run it with su.?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **Selenium** for it but you need to install webdriver before

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```